# show message function does not work

Tags: angularjs

Trying my first ng-show sample. How can I get this function to work?

html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="todocontroller">
        <button ng-click="addCount()">Increment</button>count:{{count}}
        <div ng-visible="msgvisible">too many clicks</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

js

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 function todocontroller($scope) {
     $scope.firstname = "";
     $scope.lastname = "";
     $scope.count = 0;

     $scope.addCount = function () {
         $scope.count++;
     }

     $scope.msgvisible = function () {
         if ($scope.count > 5) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/V548j/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass the results of your function `msgvisible` to `ngShow`.  Right now you're passing the function itself to an attribute `ngVisible`.

So change this:

```
<div ng-visible="msgvisible">too many clicks</div>
```

To this:

```
<div ng-show="msgvisible()">too many clicks</div>
```

And you're set:  [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V548j/3/)